# Simple Python code for Text-to-Speech using IBM Watson

Tags: python, pycharm, ibm-watson

I have been searching for code that could help me in text to speech using ibm watson in pycharm. Please help me at an earliest

Comment: Welcome to SO. IBM Watson Text-to-Speech documentation is pretty straightforward... https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech?code=python . You will just need an IBM Watson account, enable the API and get the API Key and an url

Comment: do i have to use the entire code for just to hear the text ?please help me with the code...

Comment: We are not here to do the coding for you, but to create a community wiki.  Show us your best attempt, what issues have you faced and we'll be glad to help https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @CarlosSR whats the output of the given code? It is just successfully executing with process code 0. I am not getting to hear anything.

Comment: Which code are you running?

Answer (score 4):

You can find most of this code in [IBM Watson Documentation](http://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech?code=python)

First you need ibmwatson package installed, then you need to authenticate yourself vía [API Key](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson?topic=watson-iam) and url. Only after you have established your connection, you can call the `synthesize` function.

```py
pip install --upgrade "ibm-watson>=4.4.0"

from ibm_watson import TextToSpeechV1
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('{apikey}')
text_to_speech = TextToSpeechV1(
    authenticator=authenticator
)

text_to_speech.set_service_url('{url}')

with open('filename.wav','wb') as audio_file:
    audio_file.write(text_to_speech.synthesize('hello world',voice='en-US_Henry3Voice',accept='audio/mp3').get_result().content)
```